# Javascript Regex: Mask last 50% of string

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have a string

```
var unmasked = 'AwesomeFatGorilla'
```

What I want to do is mask 50%+ of the string from the end.

```
var masked = unmasked.replace( //REGEX//, '•')
```

After replacing, the masked string should look like the following:

```
AwesomeF•••••••••
```

Since there were 17 letters in my unmasked string, the last 9 letters were masked. Are there any Regex that works with this?

Comment: Do you necessarily need a Regex? You can do this without any...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple alternative, without Regex:

```js
var unmasked = 'AwesomeFatGorilla'
var masked = unmasked.slice(0, Math.floor(unmasked.length) / 2) + "•".repeat(Math.ceil(unmasked.length / 2));
console.log(masked)
```

<s>You have to adjust the math for odd lengths</s> Thanks to [Rhyono comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981282/rhyono) below, I'm using `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()` to get the behaviour you want for odd lengths.

Comment: Just add Math.floor() to the first one and Math.ceil() on the second?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But ultimately OP is the one that has to decide what to do with odd numbers...

Comment: But he already did: "Since there were 17 letters in my unmasked string, the last 9 letters were masked."

Comment: @Rhyono I totally missed that sentence! Thanks for showing it.

Comment: Instead of `Math.floor(unmasked.length/2)` you can also use a bit shift since you divide by 2: `unmasked.length >> 1`. This way it returns the integer part of the division.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte actually my first choice would be `~~`, but I've learnt some people don't like bitwise operators... The main complaint is that they are not *readable*.

Comment: I suggested this one because it divides by 2 and "truncates" at the same time.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Sure, it's a nice suggestion, and definitely the faster option.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex `.(?!.{n})`:

```js
var unmasked = 'AwesomeFatGorilla'
var num = Math.ceil(unmasked.length / 2)
console.log(unmasked.replace(new RegExp(".(?!.{" + num + "})", "g"), "•"))
```